# for Binary tree, suppose there is n node, how many different structure can I construct?

Tags: binary-tree, catalan

Consider a binary tree with *n* nodes. How many different possible binary trees structures are there?

I tried something like:

```
n   number of different structure:

1        1
2        4
3        16
```

so is that 4(n-1)  for n >1 ;  1 for n == 1?

Comment: Try a couple simple cases. If n = 2, your equation states that there will be 4 different structures, when there could only be 2... Maybe 2 raised to some power? (hint hint)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of different binary trees that can be formed using n nodes is given by the nth Catalan number.

```
number of nodes (n)   binary trees C(n)  
1                     1  
2                     2  
3                     5  
4                     14
```

See:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: Ouais Alsharif is correct! I incorrectly stated that Catalan series. His edit was reviewed in haste.

Answer (score 5):

The previous answer by Adrian Toman is true when the value of the node is not important, only the structure of the tree is considered (Refer the same wikipedia link).

When the node value is also important, the calculation is different. The Catalan number gives you the number of different possible structures of the tree. Now, you can arrange the nodes in each of those structures (permutation). Hence total number of different trees for n nodes where value of node is important is given by the formula -

nth Catalan number * n!

```
nodes (n)    trees C(n) * n!
1            1
2            4 (= 2 * 2)
3            30 (= 5 * 6)
4            336 (= 14 * 24)
```